# iproute2 interface statistics seem wrong

Tags: linux, iproute2

For some reason, `ip -s link` does not show the same numbers as `/proc/net/dev`, specifically the overrun count.

For a given interface, ip shows no overrun packets:

```
$ ip -s link show eth-ext1
7: eth-ext1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a2:0d:00:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    1038103044434 1099087192 0       0       0       401298  
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    543051882227 844808055 0       0       0       0
```

While in `proc` we see non-zero overrun (which is what I am assuming `fifo` is referring to):

```
$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
[...]
eth-ext1: 1038106099296 1099090833    0    0 467554     0          0    401301 543052535442 844810749    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

I'm inclined to believe that there actually were overrun packets on the interface, so it appears that the output of `ip link` is not correct. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fifo and overrun are not the same. Just type ip -s -s a, there would be something like this

```
RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
53152      864      0       0       0       0
RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
           0        0       0       0       0
TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
53152      864      0       0       0       0
TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
           0        0       0       0       0
```

overrun — the total number of receiver overruns resulting in dropped packets.
As a rule, if the interface is overrun, it means serious problems in the kernel or
that your machine is too slow for this interface.

fifo (file input file output) errors

Comment: Can you also explain the different meaning?

Comment: You can read about it there http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs70/ip-cref.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I think I got confused between the two because `netstat -i` actually shows the FIFO count as `RX-OVR`.